# How to get URL response and parse JSON response in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am having Function like this.How can I get response and parse coming json response?

```
function load_login() {
    document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="http://<?php echo $proip; ?>/cgi-bin/dologin?login&username=admin&password=admin"></object>';
}
```

Comment: url response of what? all you're doing is hiding the element and changing its innerHTML

Comment: There is indeed no request being done here.

Comment: I added this function on 'onclick'.so once I click link this function get called

Answer (score 0):

```
To get a response, you need to hit the server with AJAX call.Most simply in jquery ,like below:

$.ajax({
 url:"",//pass the api `enter code here`
 data:{},// your url endpoints you want to send to server
 success:function(data)
{ 
//if server responded with status code 200,then you will get server response in the data object
 },
error:function()
{
```

server responds with error code 
    }

```
});
```

Once you are able to get response,you can use JSON.parse() method for array conversion.

Comment: didn't get any response

Comment: you might be getting some error then?could you share?

Comment: <html>
<head><title>Configure</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="content1"> </div>
</body>
<script>

      
      function load_login(){
//      document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = "hidden";

            document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="http://<?php echo $proip; ?>/manager?action=login&Username=admin&Secret=admin&time=<?php echo $time;?>" ></object>';
  }
setTimeout("load_login()",1000);
</script>
</html>----this is what i am doing.I got response. but don't know where to store n get it

Comment: this is not response,you are getting DOM structure.Use ajax to interact with server. pass your PHP file link in the URL as i answered above.

Comment: <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getResponse()
            {
             
             $.ajax({
               
                url: 'http://192.168.50.123/manager?action=login',
               data:{
  'Username':'admin',
  'Secret':'admin',
  'time':'1439311916'
               
               },
               
                success: function(data) 
                { alert('got here with data'); },
                error: function() { alert('something bad happened'); }
                });}
        </script>
      </head>
   </html>

Comment: this is what I did..but no luck:(

Comment: remove semi colon after URL and create http link. http://192.168.50.123/manager?action=login

Answer (score 0):

```
function submit()
{   var userName = $("#username").val();
    var passWord = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
     url:"login.php" ,// let say your php file name within same location
     method:POST,
     data:{
      username:userName,
      password:passWord
     },
     success:function(data){
         console.log(data)
     },
     error:function()
     {
      console.log(error);
     }
    });
}

<html>
<body>
<form>
username:<input type="text" id="username"/>
password:<input type="password" id="password" />
</form>
<button type="button" id="submit-button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>

hope it works for you!!
```

Comment: I got some response but got error           XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.50.47/manager?action=login&Username=admin&Secret=admin&time=1439314865. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.                                                                                                              Origin 'http://192.168.50.138' is therefore not allowed access.
config.php:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined

Comment: might be you are not able to match with the server endpoints and use method  POST.Share you PHP file if possible.

Comment: <?php

$soap_do = curl_init();
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,"http://192.168.50.47/manager?action=login&Username=admin&Secret=admin&time=1439311916");
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
$result =curl_exec($soap_do);
?>

Comment: <html>
<body>
<form>
</form>
<button type="button" id="submit-button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function submit()
{   /*var userName = $("Username").val();
    var passWord = $("Secret").val();*/
    $.ajax({
     url:"http://192.168.50.47/manager?action=login",
      data:{
      'Username':'admin',
      'Secret':'admin',
      'time':'1439314865'
     },
   success:function(data){
     console.log(data)
     },
    error:function()
     {console.log(error);}
    });}</script>

Comment: now got working but my url is like.http://192.168.50.123/manager?action=login data part doesn't go

Comment: check in what format server accepts data? is it serialized way?above one is JSON format.